# How to determine what one to use - next(); or dequeue();?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

Is there any difference if I do:

```
$queue.queue(function(next){
   //...
   next();
}).queue(function(next){
   //...
   next();
});
```

versus

```
$queue.queue(function(){
   //...
   $(this).dequeue();
}).queue(function(){
   //...
   $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Do they do the same thing?

What are the differences and which should I use?

It's weird cause the jQuery docs does not really mention `.next()`, they always say to use `.dequeue()` but at my workplace people use the `.next()` function so this has got me rather confused.

Comment: How is this an [tag:optimization] question?

Comment: What `next()` does is documented just fine in [the docs for `.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2): "As of jQuery 1.4, the function that's called is passed another function as the first argument. When called, this automatically dequeues the next item and keeps the queue moving."

Comment: I added Optimization because, it states that optimization is the act of improving a method or design. I am looking for the best method for use of these functions so therefore i am looking to 'optimize' my code... Makes 100% sense to me!

Comment: That seems like stretching the semantics of the term a little too far, especially since you ignore the second half of the tag wiki definition, and considering that vague questions of the form "What is the best way to do X?" tend to get closed as "not constructive".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That I know of, there is no difference.  I'm not sure why one would be preferable to the other or why they are both mentioned as that is confusing to me.

Looking at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js we see:

```
1915 next = function() {
         jQuery.dequeue( elem, type );
     };
```

...in the `jQuery.dequeue` method.  This is called a bit later on (on line 1936) as `fn.call(elem, next, hooks)`.  You see that `next` is the first parameter in the `queue` callback, and `fn` is `queue` at that time.

Looking ahead, we see

```
1983 dequeue: function( type ) {
         return this.each(function() {
             jQuery.dequeue( this, type );
         });
     },
```

This is defined on `jQuery.fn`, so that is the function called by `$(this).dequeue`.  However, this does exactly the same thing.  The only difference is the element that is dequeued.  In `fn.dequeue` it loops over the collection, but that will only be one element for `$(this)`.

If we look back, we see what `elem` is though:

```
1908 dequeue: function( elem, type ) {
```

...hey, wait a second .. it's `this` (when called from `$(this).dequeue`)!  Thus you can see that they do exactly the same thing.  `$("some other collection").dequeue` would work differently, though.

Calling `next()` saves you an additional `.each` call, so I guess that would be faster.

By the way, you don't have to call it `next` in the callback since you can rename parameters to whatever you want.

EDIT: Per my mini-discussion with my illustrious colleague @FabrícioMatté, there can actually be a difference in functionality between `next()` and `$(this).dequeue()`, specifically when not using the standard `fx` queue.  When the `next` function is created, it is set to call `$.dequeue` with the type acquired from the `queue` already, but `$.fn.dequeue` takes the type as an argument.  This is possibly even more motivation to stick with `next()`, although I've never actually seen someone use anything other than the standard effects queue practically.

Comment: Very well explained thank you. It makes sense now when laid out the way you have.

Comment: +1 for the catch about non-`fx` queues, edited my answer as well to comply with that. `=]`

Answer (score 4):

Both [`jQuery.fn.dequeue`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/queue.js#L96) and the [`next`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/queue.js#L28) function are simply wrappers for [`jQuery.dequeue`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/queue.js#L21), passing the same set of arguments in both of your examples.

---

(Up to date as of jQuery 1.9.1)

For the next function parameters: `type` is an optional parameter indicating the queue, defaults to `fx` which is jQuery's default animation queue. `element` is a DOM element reference.

`$.fn.dequeue`:

```
dequeue: function( type ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        jQuery.dequeue( this, type );
    });
}
```

`$().dequeue` simply calls `$.dequeue` for each element contained inside the jQuery object.

Your use case `$(this).dequeue()` will call `$.dequeue` a single time with the element initially reference by `this`.

Similarly, `next` will pass a single element reference to `$.dequeue`, which is the current element having its queue dequeued:

```
next = function() {
    jQuery.dequeue( elem, type );
};
```

In other words, these are essentially the same. `next` is a little more direct as it doesn't have an iteration wrapper, therefore `next()` should be some microseconds faster than `$.fn.dequeue()`.

The main difference is that you can call `.dequeue()` on multiple elements and it will dequeue each one of them, while `next()` is associated directly with the element that has its queue being dequeued.

For use-cases where you have `$(this).dequeue()` inside the callback, this is irrelevant. `$.fn.dequeue` is useful when starting to dequeue one or more elements. `$(this).dequeue()` has an equivalent outcome than `next()`, but the latter will provide a microseconds gain in this case.

---

As noted by **@Explosion Pills** in the comments, there is yet one more peculiarity when dealing with non-`fx` queues:

`$(this).dequeue()` without the `type` argument will dequeue the default queue (`fx`) so non-`fx` queues require the name to be passed as parameter to `.dequeue()`, while `.next()` seeks up its creation scope's chain and automatically retrieves the `type` inside the `$.dequeue()` scope that created the `next` function object.

Therefore, when using a non-`fx` queue, you will have to pass the queue name to `$().dequeue(queueIdentifier)`, while `.next()` will always dequeue in the queue that your callback belongs to.

Comment: I was about to edit my answer to comment on the fact that `$.fn.dequeue` takes `type` as an argument, but `next` is defined with `type` acquired from the `queue` binding.  This means that `$(this).dequeue` apparently does not work with non-`fx` queues without an additional argument whereas `next()` would.  Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, absolutely. `$(this).dequeue()` without the `type` argument will dequeue the default queue (`fx`) so non-`fx` queues require the queue name to be passed as parameter while `.next()` "inherits" the previously passed `type`. Nice spot. `=]`